# How to download file from kinvey in android

Tags: android, kinvey

Trying to download publicly accessible file from kinvey to android app
tried following code,

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(videoName);
        FileMetaData meta = new FileMetaData(videoName);
        meta.setId(videoName);
        kinveyClient.file().downloadWithTTL(meta.getId(), 1200000, fos, new DownloaderProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) throws IOException {
                Log.i("", "progress updated: " + downloader.getDownloadState());
                final String state = new String(downloader.getDownloadState().toString());

                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //tProgress.setText((tProgress.getText() == null) ? state : tProgress.getText() + "\n" + state)
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            }
        });
```

getting event success but data is not being received. any idea how this will work??

getting error like this :

```
failure com.kinvey.java.core.KinveyJsonResponseException: InsufficientCredentials
                                                          The credentials used to authenticate this request are not authorized to run this operation. Please retry your request with appropriate credentials
```

Comment: Apparently the `progressChanged` method is called on the MainThread already, why do you use the `runOnUiThread`?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this is how you are supposed to use the value you get from `getDownloadState()` . In order to get the progress of your download, you need to first check the downloadState is equal to `DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS` value, and then use the `download.getProgress()` method to get the progress, then you can use this to update the value on your progress slider, (you shouldn't be converting these values to string using the `toString()` method like you've done above.

```
public void progressChanged(MediaHttpDownloader downloader) throws IOException {
  switch (downloader.getDownloadState()) {
    case DOWNLOAD_IN_PROGRESS:
      //Download in progress
      //Download percentage:  + downloader.getProgress()
      break;
    case DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE:
      //Download Completed!
      break;
  }
}
```

Code taken from [documentation here](http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/reference/api/java/reference/com/kinvey/java/core/DownloaderProgressListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

Nayana,

You might be getting this error because user does not have permission to access that file. You can try following to solve your issue:

- If you make the file publicly readable, all authenticated users will be able to access that particular file.
- You can make the file accessible by adding read/write permissions for
  few users in ACL.

Also check the documentation for Access Control List:
http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/security#entityanduserpermissions

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support